# Can't execute queries on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

For some reason queries that have worked in Management Studio in the past no longer function. A query such as `SELECT * FROM Users` no longer works, but will work if I type the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SmartTapp].[dbo].[users]
```

The error message I get is:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'users'.

This occurs for all tables.

I'm not seeing anything SQL related in the Event Viewer.  I haven't done anything to the server that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're connected to the right database as in following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you So Very Much!... I thought I had a virus or was hacked.  I can't clicked answered for the next 10 minutes.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon It's little things all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to select database context from object explorer click on the dropdown list and select the database which contains Users table.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the the target database (or db table) before [New Query] from the Toolbar or select New Query from the Right-Click context menu if you click on the database icon itself.